# laravel passing data from controller to view

Tags: laravel

my `controller` having the below format. how can i transfer to `view` in `laravel`

i tried `->with($inboxMessage)` . The browser not even completely loaded. It's loading for a lifetime.

```
        $inboxMessage[] = [
        'messageId' => $message_id,
        'messageSnippet' => $snippet,
        'messageSubject' => $message_subject,
        'messageDate' => $message_date,
        'messageSender' => $message_sender
        ];
```

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: how to retrieve it in the view

Comment: Please read the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master). This is basic stuff, and it’s covered in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
return view("view_name",['data'=>$inboxMessage]);
```

and in view you can access using `foreach loop` or use `print_r($data)`

in view if you are using blade template then

```
@foreach($data as $val)

{{$val->messageId}}


@endforeach
```

or else use normal foreach loop

Comment: @if you are using blade template then your view name is like viewname.blade.php or else  viewname.php

Answer (score 1):

you can return your view in controller with data like below

```
return view('viewname', ['inboxMessage' => $inboxMessage]);
```

now `$inboxMessage` will available in view.

Answer (score 1):

```
return view("path to your view", compact('inboxMessage'));
```